# Block Caribou - again (22.04)

Tags: 22.04, onscreen-keyboard

I have a Dell XPS 9310 with touch screen, Ubuntu 22.04 (using X11). It's not a 2-in-1, so the keyboard cannot be 'folded away'. I would like to completely disable the onscreen keyboard.

Of course, there are many suggestions out there, but they do not work on 22.04 (and even on 20.04 didn't work perfectly). For example, 'block caribou' is not

So - how can I completely disable the onscreen keyboard / Caribou (in 22.04, with X11)?

Answer (score 1):

you can install the gnome extension:
[Block Caribou 36](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3222/block-caribou-36/)

I think you may need to disable the extension version verification using:

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell disable-extension-version-validation "true"`

Comment: Thank you - that's very much appreciated and welcome to askubuntu. I used to use Block Caribou on 20.04, but it didn't really persistently hide Caribou. I'll see whether it makes a difference on 22.04, maybe it works better. Many thanks!

Comment: Hi again - thanks again for the comment. I have installed Block Caribou 36, but it functions much the same as on 20.04. I..e., it works sometimes, but not very reliably.